# How to sync many to many with a pivot value?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

```
class User extends \Eloquent {
 public function cards() {
       return $this->belongsToMany('Card','user_card')->withPivot('sort')->orderBy('user_card.order', 'asc');
    }

}
```

I can attach the cards via `$user->sync(Input::get("card_ids",[]))` however I am hitting a wall trying to figure out how to update the pivot value "sort" to be the values of `array_keys(Input::get("card_ids",[]))` [basically the order that the user submitted them in]

Is this possible with eloquent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for syncing pivot columns is this:

```
$user->roles()->sync(array(1 => array('expires' => true)));
```

To achieve that you can first use `array_flip` to switch keys with values and then `array_map` to bring the value in the desired format:

```
$cards = Input::get('card_ids', []);
$cards = array_flip($cards);
$cards = array_map(function($sort){
    return array('sort' => $sort);
}, $cards);
$user->cards()->sync($cards);
```